# How to make the android spinner active?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android programming the code below will make the end user choose what section he wants to see and display a list view. i can't make the spinner active, it only shows one list view even though i am choosing different sections.

```
public class TeacherClasses extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,View.OnClickListener{
public String[] Section1 = {"Bonilla, Abbie", "Hernando, Roland Joseph", "Ko, Kritofer", "Manaig, Kathleen",
        "Olalia, Jerome","Rosario, Kyle", "Sevilla, Karen", "Tancioco, Eron", "Villena, Mark" };
public String[] Section2 = {"Chavez, Stephanie", "Espana, Bren Alfred", "Faro, Ede", "Gonzales, Venice",
        "Magora, Joshua James","Roman, Jairah", "Ramirez, Stephanie", "Tiboli, Jamalul", "Torrazo, Nicole" };
public String[] Section3 = {"Arbonida, Caye Anne", "De Guzman, Patricia", "Escandor, Jennifer", "Marzan, Rann",
        "Menorca, Paula","Payofelin, Marlo", "Pimentel, Iris Coleen", "Queen, Elizabeth", "Unggoy, Monkey" };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_classes);
    Button btn_Sections = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Sections);
    btn_Sections.setOnClickListener(this);
    CreateList();
}
private void CreateList() {

    Spinner spn_Sections = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_Sections);
    List<String> Sections = new ArrayList<String>();
    Sections.add("Section 1");
    Sections.add("Section 2");
    Sections.add("Section 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Sections);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn_Sections.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    ListAdapter ClassAdapter = null;
    String s = spn_Sections.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (s.equals("Section 1")) {
        ClassAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Section1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Section 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (s.equals("Section 2")) {
        ClassAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Section2);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Section 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (s.equals("Section 3")) {
        ClassAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Section3);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Section 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    ListView MyClasses = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_ClassList);
    MyClasses.setAdapter(ClassAdapter);
    MyClasses.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}
```

Comment: Dude please follow the java conventions in your code.

Comment: set you Adapters on spinnerItemClicklistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this method instead:

```
private void CreateList() {

    Spinner spn_Sections = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_Sections);
    List<String> Sections = new ArrayList<String>();
    Sections.add("Section 1");
    Sections.add("Section 2");
    Sections.add("Section 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Sections);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn_Sections.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    spn_Sections.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ClassAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Section1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Section 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ClassAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Section2);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Section 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ClassAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Section3);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Section 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            // sometimes you need nothing here
        }
    });

    ListView MyClasses = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_ClassList);
    MyClasses.setAdapter(ClassAdapter);
    MyClasses.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
```

you have to set `setOnItemSelectedListener` listener for `spinner`

Also Declare globally;

```
ListAdapter ClassAdapter = null;
```

Comment: this give me some errors
1. Class Adapter -- it says "Variable Class Adapter is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final
2. In the (this, android.R.layout) -- it says "Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(anonymous.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, int,java.lang.String[])
3. In the Toast -- it says "Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,java.lang.String[],int)

What should I do now? Thanks @rafsanahmad007